# Random function prediction in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, random-seed

According to the documentation of Random library, assuming the developer does not provide any seed(None) the function uses the system current time as a seed(time.time()).

Unfortunately, it seems the output doe not reflects the documentation

```
print(random.randrange(1,10))
a=time.time()
.
.
.
.
random.seed(a)
print(random.randrange(1,10))
```

The code above produces 2 different outputs so assuming I use windows 10(for those who might think in the direction of urandom supplier) and Python 3 my questions are:

1.Why the above code does not produces the same output

2.How canI make it produces the same output

3.When I tried to find the seed assignment part in Random.py I couldn't find anywhere time.time() assignment to Random.seed so If someone can refers to that part I will be grateful

Comment: Well of course they're different, `time.time()` will not be the same for two consecutive calls...

Comment: how do you expect to produce the same random values? the time at the first instruction is different at the time at the second instruction

Comment: time has elapsed between your first two lines of code...

Comment: The time flies by :) The clock at the time of the execution of `random.randrange(1,10)` is not the same as the time at the execution of `time.time()`.

Comment: _"How can I make it produces the same output"_: Capture the time _first_, and use _that time_ to seed both times.

Comment: I run time.time() before and after print(random.randrange(1,10)) and it produced the same time so I assume saving the time.time() right after the random call is enough.But  don't let that bothers you, I also tried it with saving the time before the random call

Comment: The documentation says "None or no argument seeds from current time," not from `time.time()`. `time.time()` does not report the current time. It reports its approximation.

Comment: So you imply that they used different function? Because I saw in multiple sources similiar implementation with time.time()

Comment: You cannot assume that `random.random()` seeds from `time.time()` because the documentation does not mention `time.time()`. Apparently, `random.random()` seeds from a high-resolution timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually an interesting question.

First, you can potentially get the same result from consecutive calls to `time.time()` but mainly due to precision.

```py
In [36]: a=time.time(); b=time.time()

In [37]: b-a
Out[37]: 0.0
```

Now let's jump into the questions:

1. It does not produce the same output because of how the initial seed is generated. If you look at the [random.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/caff2934f46510920a6169e192707d59e9c55f6b/Lib/random.py#L125) source code for `seed()` you'll see it specifies

> ```
> def seed(self, a=None, version=2):
>    """Initialize internal state from a seed.
>    The only supported seed types are None, int, float,
>    str, bytes, and bytearray.
>    None or no argument seeds from current time or from an operating
>    system specific randomness source if available.
> ```

Because there is no reference to `time.time()` you can't assume it uses it. In fact, you can look at the source for [the CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_randommodule.c) implementation (if you understand C). One of the ways it helps guarantee a random seed if necessary is this:

```
static void
random_seed_time_pid(RandomObject *self)
{
    _PyTime_t now;
    uint32_t key[5];

    now = _PyTime_GetSystemClock();
    key[0] = (uint32_t)(now & 0xffffffffU);
    key[1] = (uint32_t)(now >> 32);

    key[2] = (uint32_t)getpid();

    now = _PyTime_GetMonotonicClock();
    key[3] = (uint32_t)(now & 0xffffffffU);
    key[4] = (uint32_t)(now >> 32);

    init_by_array(self, key, Py_ARRAY_LENGTH(key));
}
```

There are multiple calls to different clocks AND a process ID. Nothing about `time.time()`. And because of how the seed is generated there, it's pretty impossible for two consecutive seeds to be the same.

2. If you want something to produce the same output, you need to seed it the same.

```py
In [42]: import random

In [43]: a = time.time()

In [44]: random.seed(a)

In [45]: random.randrange(100)
Out[45]: 98

In [46]: random.randrange(100)
Out[46]: 94

In [47]: random.seed(a)  # Reset

In [48]: random.randrange(100)
Out[48]: 98
```

It doesn't need to be a number, though. You can seed with a lot of different options.

3. Hopefully the source code provided above address that.

Comment: First of all thank you for your detailed answer.So If the seed generated by two different clocks which I can hardly predict and PID which I can't predict at all then Random library is perfectly secure.This conclusion contradicts previous research I made where the Random library is not safe for cryptography purposes and can be exploited

Comment: It is not cryptographically secure. It implements Mersenne Twister. See http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/efaq.html#:~:text=Mersenne%20Twister%20is%20not%20cryptographically,based%20on%20a%20linear%20recursion.&text=To%20make%20it%20secure%2C%20you,8%20of%20the%20original%20one).

Comment: I should clarify: The seeding has nothing to do with it being cryptographically secure. The MT algorithm itself is not secure since the output can be predictable.